# SSRS - Default to show ALL values if parameter is left blank

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

My SSRS report displays a date range (2 parameters) and a multi-selectable value parameter for a field called "MeterNumber".

What I want is for the default value of the multi-selectable parameter to show ALL values until the user specifies one of the values in the list.

I've tried doing this by setting the general tab in the parameter properties to "Allow Multiple Values", and the Available and Default values to equaling the same value fields from the same dataset, but no go.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you set a default value for `@StartDate` and `@EndDate` parameters?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Yes. @ StartDate defaults to the first day of the month and @ EndDate defaults to the last day of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same dataset that populates the Available Values of the parameter, to populate the Default Values of the parameter.

Then by default, all values are selected when the user first opens the report.

Comment: That's how I have my current parameters. If this helps, here is my dataset query. The parameter in question is the MeterNumber:


SELECT AC.MeterNumber, AC.AccountName, AMR.MeterRead, AMR.ReadDate, AMR.CorrectedMMBTU, AMR.AccountID
FROM tblAccountMeterRead AMR
 JOIN tblAccount AC
 ON AC.AccountID = AMR.AccountID
WHERE AMR.ReadDate BETWEEN @ StartDate AND @ EndDate
AND AMR.MeterRead <> '0'

Comment: The query doesn't matter, if you use the same dataset for the defaults that you use for available values, then all values should be checked by default.   There must be something else you are doing wrong that isn't mentioned in your question.   Can you add some screenshots of your parameter property pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign minimum date and maximum date in your back-end if your date start and date end is empty or null (*remember the min date in sql is `1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM` and max date is `12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM` so your date format should be like that*). So when its passed on your parameter it will get all the data within that minimum start date and maximum end date.

This is how you are going to assign min date time in c#

```
DateTime dateStart = SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value;
```

and max date

```
DateTime dateEnd = SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any blank and/or null values for MeterNumber in the dataset? This can cause issues with Parameter values. Since in your case you need multiple values, then you can't have null values. Just make sure Allow blank value ("") and Allow multiple values are selected. Then, make sure you don't have NULL values in the MeterNumber column. If you do, then convert to empty string, i.e., `ISNULL(AC.MeterNumber, '') as MeterNumber`

Answer (score 0):

Just had the exact same problem @Byronyk, however just realised what the issue was (Also aware this post is very old, this is more for those who stumble upon this!)

The issue I found was that I had one extra Value in the available values than in the Default Values, and as such it threw out the default selections.

Once I realised and added it in, the default values were selected again.

I suspect this is the issue, as the date worked fine, the issue was in the 'MeterNumber' parameter